Why does edit click is not working for MUIDatatable?
I've below piece code for which I'm trying to achieve is provide 'edit' and 'add new record' options to the users using MUIDataTable but when I click on 'edit' button I don't see modal popup opening. However when I click on 'create new', it opens modal pop-up.
I need to display edited record on modal popup and provide save, cancel in that modal.
I'm new to react and MUI controls, any help appreciated.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

import {
  Button,
  Select,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  TextField,
  DialogActions
} from "@mui/material";

function ModalBox({ open, handleClose, handleSave, selectedData }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    dname: "",
    dsource: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedData) {
      setState({
        dname: selectedData[1],
        dsource: selectedData[2]
      });
    }
  }, [selectedData]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleEditSave = () => {
    handleSave(state.dname, state.dsource);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit Row</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To edit this row, please enter the new values here.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            name="dname"
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            value={state.dname}
            onChange={handleChange}
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            margin="dense"
            id="provider"
            name="dsource"
            label="Provider"
            type="text"
            value={state.dsource}
            onChange={handleChange}
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleEditSave} color="primary">
            Save
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

function Companies() {
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Edit",
      options: {
        filter: false,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => (
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => {
              const selectedRow = data.find((row) => row[0] === value);
              setEditModalOpen(true);
              setSelectedData(selectedRow);
            }}
          >
            Edit
          </Button>
        ),
      },
    },
    "Id",
    "Name",
    "Provider",
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  let id = 0;
  function createData(name, provider) {
    id += 1;
    return [id, name, provider];
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [
      createData("Dummy1", "oracle"),
      createData("Dummy2", "mssql"),
      createData("Dummy3", "oracle"),
    ];
    setData(data);
  }, []);

  const options = {
    filterType: "checkbox",
  };

  const [editModalOpen, setEditModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState(null);

  const handleSave = (dname, dsource) => {
    const updatedData = data.map((row) => {
      if (row[0] === selectedData[0]) {
        return [row[0], dname, dsource];
      }
      return row;
    });
    setData(updatedData);
    setEditModalOpen(false);
    setSelectedData(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="f-height fx-column-cont">
      <div>
        <ModalBox
          open={editModalOpen}
          handleClose={() => setEditModalOpen(false)}
          handleSave={handleSave}
          selectedData={selectedData}
        />
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Test Source"}
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Companies;


I was able to figure out the solution. Here's the working sample in case anyone needs it.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

import {


Button,
  Select,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  TextField,
  DialogActions
} from "@mui/material";

function ModalBox({ open, handleClose, handleSave, selectedData }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    dname: selectedData ? selectedData.dname : "",
    dsource: selectedData ? selectedData.dsource : ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedData) {
      setState({
        dname: selectedData[1],
        dsource: selectedData[2]
      });
    }
  }, [selectedData]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleEditSave = () => {
    handleSave(state.dname, state.dsource);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit Row</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To edit this row, please enter the new values here.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            name="dname"
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            value={state.dname}
            onChange={handleChange}
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            margin="dense"
            id="provider"
            name="dsource"
            label="Provider"
            type="text"
            value={state.dsource}
            onChange={handleChange}
            fullWidth
          />
          {selectedData && (
            <div>
              <p>Current Name: {selectedData[1]}</p>
              <p>Current Provider: {selectedData[2]}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleEditSave} color="primary">
            Save
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

function Companies() {
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Edit",
      options: {
        filter: false,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => (
          <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                const selectedRowIndex = tableMeta.rowIndex;
                const selectedRow = data[selectedRowIndex];
                //alert(JSON.stringify(selectedRow));
                setEditModalOpen(true);
                setSelectedData(selectedRow);
            }}
          >
        Edit
      </Button>
        ),
      },
    },
    "Id",
    "Name",
    "Provider",
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  let id = 0;
  function createData(name, provider) {
    id += 1;
    return [id, name, provider];
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [
      createData("Dummy1", "oracle"),
      createData("Dummy2", "mssql"),
      createData("Dummy3", "oracle"),
    ];
    setData(data);
  }, []);

  const options = {
    filterType: "checkbox",
  };

  const [editModalOpen, setEditModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState(null);

  const handleSave = (dname, dsource) => {
    const selectedIndex = data.findIndex((row) => row[0] === selectedData[0]);
    if (selectedIndex !== -1) {
      const updatedRow = [selectedData[0], dname, dsource];
      const updatedData = [...data];
      updatedData[selectedIndex] = updatedRow;
      setData(updatedData);
    }
    setEditModalOpen(false);
    setSelectedData(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="f-height fx-column-cont">
      <div>
        <ModalBox
          open={editModalOpen}
          handleClose={() => setEditModalOpen(false)}
          handleSave={handleSave}
          selectedData={selectedData}
        />
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Test Source"}
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Companies;


Code is modified to save data table values along with the table index and use that index value to populate into modal popup when user clicks on edit button.
